# how to remove edges within selective surface on mesh viewer?

Tags: c++, qt, computational-geometry, mesh, cgal

I'm using CGAL [edge collapsing](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_simplification/Surface_mesh_simplification_2edge_collapse_surface_mesh_8cpp-example.html) to remove edges on mesh and it's working successfully .

But I want to run the edge collapsing process within selected surface on mesh viewer .

I preview the Geomview (.off ) using the following code:

```
QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget(viewer);
centralWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum,QSizePolicy::Maximum);
setCentralWidget( new CGAL::SimpleLCCViewerQt<LCC, CGAL::DefaultColorFunctorLCC>(&qWin ,
                  lcc,
                  "Basic LCC Viewer",
                  false,
                   fcolor ) );
show();
```

So, How Can I select specific surface region on mesh viewer and apply the edge collapsing on the selected surface only ?

I appreciate any help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a selection operation in the viewer. This is not straightforward.
You need for example to track the mouse event, in order to drag a rectangle.
Then you need to iterate through all the darts, and select all the ones that are in the rectangle.

Comment: thanks @gdamiand , any useful links or suggested libs,tools, please?

Comment: You don't use any libs; everything is available in libqglviewer which is used by basic viewers.